# CDK: How to get L2 construct instance from L1 (CFN)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

In my CDK code there is a low-lavel `ecs.CfnTaskDefinition` task definition.

```python
my_task_definition = aws_cdk.ecs.CfnTaskDefinition(
    scope=self,
    id="my_task_definition",
    # rest of the parameters...
)
```

I want to use this task definition to a create a Ecs service, like this.

```python
my_service = aws_cdk.ecs.Ec2Service(
    scope=self,
    id="my_service",
    cluster=my_cluster,
    task_definition=my_task_definition,  # NOT COMPATIBLE
    desired_count=1,
    # rest of the parameters..
)
```

But as the `task_definition` argument of `Ec2Service` should be an instance of `aws_cdk.aws_ecs.TaskDefinition`; it's not possible to use `my_task_definition` here, which is instance of `aws_cdk.aws_ecs.CfnTaskDefinition`.

So the question is it possible to get `aws_cdk.aws_ecs.TaskDefinition` object from `aws_cdk.aws_ecs.CfnTaskDefinition` instance?

Comment: I mostly dev in typescript but it should just be a matter of implementing the interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to get aws_cdk.aws_ecs.TaskDefinition object from aws_cdk.aws_ecs.CfnTaskDefinition instance?

❌ No.  You cannot get a L2 `Something` construct from a L1 `CfnSomething`.  You can get a L2 `ISomething` [interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with.html#work-with-library-interfaces) construct with [from_task_definition_arn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_ecs/TaskDefinition.html#aws_cdk.aws_ecs.TaskDefinition.from_task_definition_arn) (see below).  But the `task_definition` prop won't accept the interface type.

✅ In your case, start with a L2 `TaskDefinition` or `ECSTaskDefinition` construct.  Then, if you need to muck about with the L1 attributes, use [escape hatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html#cfn_layer_resource) syntax to modify its underlying `CfnTaskDefinition`.

> How to get L2 construct instance from L1 (CFN)?

More generally, yes, there are [two ways](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.cloudformation_include-readme.html#converting-l1-resources-to-l2) to get a L2 `ISomething` from a L1 `CfnSomething`:

(1) The CDK ["unescape hatch"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cfn_layer.html#cfn_layer_unescape) syntax, but only for S3 Buckets and KMS keys:

```py
cfnBucket = CfnBucket(stack, 'CfnBucket')
bucket: IBucket = Bucket.from_cfn_bucket(cfn_bucket=cfnBucket)
```

(2) For other constructs, the `from_something_arn` [reference methods](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html#resources_external) achieve the same result.